# Determining partial derivatives via Taylor polynomials

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative

Typical Taylor series problem which has totally perplexed me. The function is $$e^{x_1x_2}\sin(x_1+x_2)$$

and the task is to solve $\partial_1^2\partial_2f(0,0)$ and $\partial_1\partial_2^3f(0,0).$ This is done by comparing co-efficients of $x_1^2x_2$ and $x_1x_2^3$. The relevant theorem here, is that a Taylor polynomial maybe written in multi-index notation, as in $$T_4(f,(0,0))=\sum_{\vert\alpha\vert\leq4}\frac{1}{\alpha}\partial^{\alpha}f(0,0)x^{\alpha}.$$

However, the taylor polynomial for $f$ at $(0,0)$ can also be written with the aid of two more elementary constructions, with $t_1=x_1x_2$ and $t_2=x_1 +x_2$ ,  as in $$e^{t_1}=1+t_1+\frac{1}{2!}t_1^2+\frac{1}{3!}t_1^3+\frac{1}{4!}t_1^4$$

and $$\sin t_2 = t_2 - \frac{1}{3!}t_2^3.$$

We can then multiply $$\Bigg(1+t_1+\frac{1}{2!}t_1^2+\frac{1}{3!}t_1^3+\frac{1}{4!}t_1^4\Bigg)\bigg(t_2 - \frac{1}{3!}t_2^3\Bigg)$$

and pick the relevant terms from here. In this case it would be $t_1t_2=(x_1x_2)(x_1 + x_2)=x_1^2x_2 + x_1x_2^2$ ( Note that the mentioned co-efficient is now $1$ ). We can now solve $\partial_1^2\partial_2f(0,0)$ from the equation, when $\alpha = (2,1)$ ( Differentiating two times in the direction of $x_1$, and once in the direction of $x_2$ )

$$\frac{1}{\alpha!}\partial_1^2\partial_2f(0,0)=\frac{1}{2!1!}\partial_1^2\partial_2f(0,0)=1$$

which would yield $$\partial_1^2\partial_2f(0,0)=(2!)(1!)(1)=2!=2$$

but the correct answer should be $1$, while $\partial_1\partial_2^3f(0,0)=0$ ( i.e the term $x_1x_2^3$ does not show up at all ). Any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note you can get other terms ... Consider the $t_2^3$ term in $\sin t_2$. This will contribute to both of your specific monomials, no?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I forgot about the binomial theorem.